# К ЧЕМУ — союз или союзное слово: "Не могу понять, к чему они?"

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, морфология, союзы

Придаточная изъяснительная должна чем-то присоединяться... Может ли предложное сочетание **к чему** выступать в роли союза или союзного слова? Попутный вопрос: есть ли аналогичные случаи с другими предложными сочетаниями?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Помню те два вопроса, но не могу понять, к чему они (задаются).* **К чему**-союзное слово, присоединяет придаточное неполное предложение. Союзное слово **часто** употребляется как предложное сочетание в косвенных падежах:

*Он знал, **к чему** следует относиться внимательно.*

*Он сообщил, **о чём** разговаривали эти двое*.

*Я ещё не знала, **с чем** мне предстоит столкнуться*.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А если "к чему они" имеет значение "что за ними скрывается", все равно "к чему" будет союзным словом, присоединяющим придаточную изъяснительную?

Comment: Да, конечно, это же неполное предложение, подставляется то, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

1. Это союзное слово. Во-первых, союзы и союзные слова, не относящиеся к именной части речи, не склоняются, а союзные слова, относящиеся к именной части речи, склоняются, поэтому союза "к чему", в отличие от союзного слова "к чему", нет. А во-2, логическое ударение на союзное слово падает, в отличие от союза:

   > То, что отношЕние периметра окружности к его диаметру было постоянное, и то, что онО превышает 3, было ясно до нашей эры.

> То, чЕм называли число π ранее, - это лудольфово число.